# Node.js bcrypt compare $2y$-hash with plain-text

Tags: php, node.js, hash, bcrypt

I got a problem with a password-hash saved in a database. This value is hashed in PHP with [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php)

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
```

where options is 'cost' => 11

Now i am programming a node-API for an iOS/Android-App and I am using [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) for handling the comparison with the compareSync-method.

For my unterstanding, there are two parameters at the method: the plain-text and the hash-value?

the hash-value starts with: $2y$ - maybe there is the problem?

If I compare the plaintext-value with the hash, I get false back.

Please help me, am I doing everything right?

Thank you for your helpful answers!

Comment: `password_hash()`, if you read the documentation, stores a random salt with the hash.

Comment: where does this stand?